# How to select N Colors from the Spectrum?

Tags: colors

Given the RGB color white `#ffffff`, how would one split this into N colors?

Imagine a Rainbow, it has 7 colors.

[image: Rainbow Image]

How would one programatically yield these 7 colors? If you can arrive at 7 colors in this known spectrum, how would one yield say 70 colors of this spectrum in the same relative order? Meaning that this rainbow would contain 10 "steps" between Orange and Yellow for example. The Orange and Yellow are no longer side by side but separated by an interpolation of color between them.